# How to open multiple windows using selenium webdriver?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver

I have to check switching behavior of sites but when i test it on site http://www.baidu.com , which in usual browsers, opens options in a new tab, opens the clicked option in the same tab while using selenium. How to make it execute as it executes normally in browsers?

Comment: you mean diff. link in diff. browser window? or in diff. tabs of same browser?

Comment: i mean different tabs of same browser. Further, i will make it open in different windows instead of different tabs

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to open link in new window :

```
        driver.get("http://www.google.com"); //Replace your URL
        WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your Element Xpath"]"));
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(link).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();

for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }

        // It will close new opened window
        driver.close();
```

You can use id or other locator for element as per your flexibility.
We are just pressing keys Shift + Up by selenium code.

Comment: Using this code still opens new url in same window/tab and the previous tab disappears. I need to have them both at same time to execute switching

Comment: I used same code , it is open link in new window and still my old window is also open. I tested code.

Comment: ,I am using same code but a second window shows opening for just a split second but in the end, result is shown in only one window and previous window is overwritten with it.

Comment: it is not overwritten , Actually it is just opening new window in full size , do you want to focus again in old window?

Comment: yes i want the second window to be opened and to get the focus back to old window

Comment: I see, I have updated code. please check. You can put wait before new window closing if you want to stay for a while in new window.